# How to create xml tags from text using java

Tags: java, xml, string, split, tags

I have annotated text file with some certain tags and after that I would like to put those tags in xml tags inside ordinary text file, the annotation example as follow:

```
The
reflection
implementation
in
Microsoft@.NET@Framework@1.0@SP3#SOFTWARE,
1.1@SP1,@2.0@SP2,@3.5.1,@and@4#MODIFIER
does
not
properly
enforce
object
permissions
```

I would like to run java script to convert the above text into the following format:

```xml
The reflection implementation in <SOFTWARE> Microsoft@.NET@Framework@1.0@SP3</SOFTWARE>, 
<MODIFIER> 1.1@SP1,@2.0@SP2,@3.5.1,@and@4 </MODIFIER> does not properly enforce 
object permissions
```

I tried with the follwoing java code:

```java
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        String split[] = line.split("\\s");
        for (String string : split) {
            if (string.indexOf("<") != -1) {

                String annotatedText = string;
                Pattern tagPattern = Pattern
                        .compile("<(\\S+?)(.*?)>(.*?)</\\1>");
                Matcher m = tagPattern.matcher(annotatedText);
```

But I got confused when I split the strings and the desired characters missing

Comment: I need to convert the results at the end into xml format. Please any help

Comment: I want to save the results of the converted text into xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt")));
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
     String split[] = line.split("#");
        if (split.length == 1)
            output.append(" " + line);
        else 
            output.append(String.format(" <%s>%s</%s>",split[1],split[0],split[1]));
}
System.out.println(output.toString().trim());
```

Output (if you remove the comma after SOFTWARE in your file) :

`The reflection implementation in <SOFTWARE>Microsoft@.NET@Framework@1.0@SP3</SOFTWARE> <MODIFIER>1.1@SP1,@2.0@SP2,@3.5.1,@and@4</MODIFIER> does not properly enforce object permissions`

Comment: I got the comma inside the tag !! <SOFTWARE,> ...</SOFTWARE,> what is the problem ?

Comment: It is difficult because i have more than 100 files which is difficult to remove all the commas

Comment: How, it has important in some parts for example, "1.1@SP1,@2.0@SP2,@3.5.1,@and@4#MODIFIER" comma is important , while in #SOFTWARE, is not important

Comment: I think I give it try, 
    else{
    String tag = split[1].replaceAll("[-+.^:,;]","");
    sbf.append(String.format("<%s>%s</%s>", tag, split[0],
      tag));
   }

Comment: I solved the problem, but how could I put the results in xml file format? please help